# send post include text and image by xmlrpc to wordpress

Tags: image, wordpress, post, xml-rpc, send

Im looking for a way to send remotely content(text and image ) by xmlrpc to wordpress but i couldn't find yet, im going to sent remotely content (text and image) over 100 post per minute to wordpress, whats the best way to do it?  thanks so much

Answer (score 0):

Use XMLRPC. Something like this:

```
$params = array(0,$username,$password,$content,true);
$request = xmlrpc_encode_request('metaWeblog.newPost',$params);
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $request);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $rpcurl);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 1);
$results = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```